# How to get rid of the extra spacing before figures?

Tags: spacing, floats

I'm using a custom class which bases on the a4paper documentclass. When I add a table or a figure which doesn't have enough place on the current page, it is moved to the next one. This is fine for me.

However, if there is no more text  after this figure, latex tries to fill in the gap and creates many smaller ones:

I want it to be just one gap at the end of the page.

Here is what I have now: 
[image: bad]

And here is what I'd like to have:
[image: good]

How can I remove the extra spacing?

**Note:** I don't want to reduce the spacing around a float - I don't care how big it is-I want to minimize the impact of the rest of the text.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Have you tried providing the instruction `\raggedbottom`?

Comment: It works, thank you! But in the documentation it is written that it applies to all pages. What if I have one page where I want to use this instruction and another one where I don't (because the vertical spaces added by latex are small)?

Comment: The opposite of `\raggedbottom` is `\flushbottom`. The commands do *not* work automatically on *all* pages of the document, unless they're placed in the preamble. If you want to have them take effect somewhere mid-document, just them where you want them to apply.

Comment: By the way, `a4paper` looks to be more of an option that's passed to a document class than a document class in and of itself.

Comment: Just don't use the `[H]` position specifier for `\begin{figure}`.

Comment: `[H]` means "leave ugly white spaces in the document", and it does what is asked.

Comment: You could also add \vfill before \begin{figure}[H] to do a single page \raggedbottom (effectively).